# Echo part of an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have queried the database in WordPress using `get_results()` and I get the following when I dump the `$myrows` variable. How do I `echo` each part?

```
array(1) {
 [0]=>object(stdClass)#215 (2) {
 ["location_id"]=> string(1) "5"
 ["location_name"]=> string(9) "Liverpool"
 }
}
```

I would like to be able to have the following the variable dumped is `$myrows`:

```
echo '<p>' . $myrows['location-name'] . '</p>';
```

Comment: In what formatting do you want them echoed out?

Comment: @Duniyadnd edited to show an answer to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing there is an array of objects (within only a single item in that array).

```
$obj = $array[0]; // Change the $array to match your variable name
echo $obj->location_id;
echo $obj->location_name;
```

---

Alternatively, you can update `get_results()` to return the items as an array of arrays.

For example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts"; // Change to suit your needs
$array = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );

$arr = $array[0]; // Change the $array to match your variable name
echo $arr['location_id'];
echo $arr['location_name'];
```

Typically, you would use `get_results()` to get multiple rows, so you would use `foreach()` or something similar:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );

foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo $row['location_id'];
    echo $row['location_name'];
}
```

If you only wanted to get a single row, you can use the `get_row($query, ARRAY_A)` method instead.

There's lot of information about the `$wpdb` class in the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Answer (score -2):

```
if echo part of an array
foreach($p as $value):
        echo $value['location_name'],"<br>";
endforeach;
```

if echo total of an array

```
foreach($p as $value):
        foreach($value as $key=>$val)
            echo ">>>>>>>",$key,"=$val<br>";
    endforeach;
```